# Django: correctly display multiple error messages for one field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-validation

I'm using django 1.5.5. for my project. I have some models, some of which have a many-to-many field to another:

```
class ScreeningFormat(CorecrmModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Film(CorecrmModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    screening_formats = models.ManyToManyField(ScreeningFormat)

class Screen(CorecrmModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    screening_formats = models.ManyToManyField(ScreeningFormat)

class FilmShow(CorecrmModel):
    film = models.ForeignKey(Film)
    screen = models.ForeignKey(Screen)
    screening_formats = models.ManyToManyField(ScreeningFormat)
```

I've created a custom admin form for FilmShow which has a `clean_screening_formats` method:

```
class FilmShowAdminForm(admin.ModelForm):
    def clean_screening_formats(self):
        # Make sure the selected screening format exists in those marked for the film
        screening_formats = self.cleaned_data['screening_formats']
        film_formats = self.cleaned_data['film'].screening_formats.all()
        sf_errors = []
        for (counter, sf) in enumerate(screening_formats):
            if sf not in film_formats:
                sf_error = forms.ValidationError('%s is not a valid screening format for %s' % (sf.name, self.cleaned_data['film'].title), code='error%s' % counter)
                sf_errors.append(sf_error)
        if any(sf_errors):
            raise forms.ValidationError(sf_errors)

        return formats
```

The actual validation check is working fine, but the output of these error messages on the admin form is a bit off. Whereas a single error message is output as (for example):

```
This field is required.
```

The output for a list of messages looks like this:

```
[u'35mm Film is not a valid screening format for Thor: The Dark World']
[u'Blu Ray is not a valid screening format for Thor: The Dark World']
```

Can anyone suggest how I could make these lists of error messages display correctly?

Edit:
I think this problem is arising from the fact that django is storing the messages slightly differently when more than one error is being raised. Example:

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> error = forms.ValidationError('This is the error message', code='lone_error')
>>> error.messages
[u'This is the error message']

>>> e1 = forms.ValidationError('This is the first error message', code='error1')
>>> e2 = forms.ValidationError('This is the second error message', code='error2')
>>> error_list = [e1, e2]
>>> el = forms.ValidationError(error_list)
>>> el.messages
[u"[u'This is the first error message']", u"[u'This is the second error message']"]
```

Could this be a bug in Django?

Comment: Just to clarify: you're looking for field level messaging?

Comment: I think I have field level messaging, I'd just like to know how to output multiple of them for one field without the "[u'']" around each of the messages

Comment: Can you post the template part where the error messages are displayed?

Comment: I'm using the default django admin template, so the error list is built from the `field.field.errors.as_ul` template tag. I'll update the question with a bit more info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implementation that you have made is only valid from Django 1.6+. Compare: [1.6 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/validation/#raising-multiple-errors) to [1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/validation/).

Before 1.6, messages were immediately converted to strings in `django.core.exceptions.ValidationError` (see code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/core/exceptions.py)):

```
class ValidationError(Exception):
    """An error while validating data."""
    def __init__(self, message, code=None, params=None):
        import operator
        from django.utils.encoding import force_text
        """
        ValidationError can be passed any object that can be printed (usually
        a string), a list of objects or a dictionary.
        """
        if isinstance(message, dict):
            self.message_dict = message
            # Reduce each list of messages into a single list.
            message = reduce(operator.add, message.values())

        if isinstance(message, list):
            self.messages = [force_text(msg) for msg in message]  #! Will output "u'<message>'"
```

In your case, instead of passing a list of `ValidationError` instances, just pass a list of strings:

```
>>> e1 = 'This is the first error message'
>>> e2 = 'This is the second error message'
>>> error_list = [e1, e2]
>>> el = forms.ValidationError(error_list)
>>> el.messages
[u'This is the first error message', u'This is the second error message']
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me so keep trying the following:

```
def clean(self):
if self.acci_anios_residencia == None:
    lista = ["Especifique un año"]
    raise ValidationError({'acci_anios_residencia': lista})
```